# "Home" is not a Constructor on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, consign

I'm using consign to autoload my applications models, routes and etc... I Have a Model that was Modeling in ES6 style and when I instanciate her it Throws me this error `TypeError: app.src.models.Home is not a constructor`
I've tried to use ES5 style but no difference. The Object that the consign create is with the models Inside but I cannot access then.

That's my class:

```
/*function Home() {

}

Home.prototype.getHomeData = function (conexao, callback) {
    conexao.query('select * from tarefas', callback)
} //IT does not work like the item below, so I will keep using ES6
*/

class Home {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Construi')
    }

    getHomeData(conexao, callback) {
        conexao.query('select * from tarefas', callback)
    }
}
module.exports = function () {
    return Home
}
```

Look:
Server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyparser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();
var consign = require('consign');
consign()
    .include('./src/routes')
    .then('./src/config/db.js')
    .then('./src/models')
    .into(app);
console.log("I'm on server.js: ", app.src.models)
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Servidor ON");
});
module.exports = app;
```

and the console returns properly `I'm on server.js:  { 'home.model': [Function: Home] }`

When I get from the Route It keeps showing me that the `app.src.models`has data, 
Console output: `I'm on the home.js and still have data + { 'home.model': [Function: Home] }`

But When I try to Instanciate the class I throws the error cited above...

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {

       console.log("I'm on the home.js and still have data +", app.src.models)
        var conexao = app.src.config.db()
        var homeData = new app.src.models.Home();

        homeData.getHomeData(conexao, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json(err)
            } else {
                res.json(result)
            }
        })
    });
}
```

if I try the below the console gets undefined:

```
console.log("I'm on the home.js and still have data +", app.src.models.Home)
```

Here is my repo, if u want https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/PM_API

Tentative 1:

On class Home i made `module.exports = new Home()` and it throws the same error

Comment: in your `Home` class export the class itself and not a function `module.exports = Home`

Comment: It throws this error TypeError: Class constructor Home cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: I've tried module.exports = new Home() and returned to the inicial error :/

Comment: `module.exports = { Home }` ?

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Where is your class loaded and how is it called? Where (in what line of which file) do you get that TypeError about the missing `new`?

Comment: @trincot, does not worked :/

Comment: @Bergi where I trye `module.exports = Home` it threows this error `TypeError: Class constructor Home cannot be invoked without 'new'` on line 12 of server.js

Comment: Dont export an instance of home (i.e. `new Home()`). Instead `export Home` or `module.export = Home`. Then where you invoke home (in `server.js`) use `new Home` to instantiate it. Your question is not accurate with the error you gave us just now in your comment.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira Uh, line 12 of the server.js you posted in your question is `app.listen(3000, function () {` which has absolutely nothing to do with `Home`. Which code really throws that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your Home class as such:

```
module.exports = { Home };
```

And import/use it as such:

```
const { Home } = require('path/to/Home.js');
const home = new Home();
home.getHomeData(...)
```

Comment: It Works, but dont bring the database information how do I know that he connected sucessfuly?

Comment: That is the expected result. `new Home()` creates a new instance of `Home`.

Comment: My bad, the table that I was querying was empty haha, but... And the consign loader? This way works! but the loader of consign should work too, dont? I mean `app.src.models.Home()`